# Integrated Windows Authentication with Apache in Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-authentication

I have a server running Windows 2000 / Apache 2.0 and PHP 5. 
I need a server that recognizes the user's login client PC that is in the same domain. 
All the tutorials I find are with IIS or Apache on Linux. 
I hope someone knows how I can do this type of authentication.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project should do what you want, although it is unmaintained:
http://mod-auth-sspi.sourceforge.net/docu/mod_auth_sspi/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/